# Depth image on amcl_demo

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, openni, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm having some trouble while trying to access the kinect depth image using amcl_demo.

When i run `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` it works well, and i can access/see topic `/camera/depth/image`.
The problem is when i run `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo map_file:=/..`. It starts all the nodes from the camera (the topic is there as well) but i can't see the depth image from the same topic before. I think i need to enable something but don't know what to do.

Hope you can help.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190483/depth-image-on-amcl_demo/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would check the launch file at `turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.alunch` and see if the parameter `depth_registration` is true. In general, setting `depth_registration` to true when running `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` (which is launched via `amcl_demo.launch`) will kill the regular `camera/depth/image`, and vice versa.

After launching `amcl_demo.launch`, try `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure` and select /camera/driver from the drop-down menu. When the `depth_registration` checkbox is checked, then `camera/depth_registered/image_raw` should display correctly, but not `camera/depth/image`. Unchecking it should swap it back.

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-08-20**:
Thank you ! Problem solved :)